Playing in third person in Desktop VRChat?
How do I play VRChat in third person on desktop?
I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while now. It used to be easy. There used to be mods for VRChat for third person, very helpful for those that can't play first person games or use a headset, but since VRChat removed mods that's not an option anymore.
There's apparently plugins now, but there doesn't seem to be any for third person yet.
There's supposedly an option for third person in the VR version of the game, but that option doesn't exist in the desktop version.
I saw a trick somewhere with moving the camera, but the camera options in the desktop version can't be moved like that.
It's also apparently possible to change the position of the camera on a model itself to achieve third person, but that would only apply to that one model and it's something that has to be done before adding the model to the game. It's not something that would work for models that are already in the game. Every single model you use would have to be created by you with the camera adjusted or you just have to never switch your model if you want stay in third person.
I've even tried getting the game to launch the VR version instead of the desktop version to make use of the options that are only available in the VR version, but Steam refuses to. Even when choosing the VR version option it just launches the desktop version anyway.
So, now in 2024, how can I play VRChat in third person on desktop?

You can't
With the introduction of EasyAntiCheat, you can't run client mods (plugins) anymore and, in the stock version of the game, there is no third person camera functionality.
In VR, this is simply the result of locomotion, which plants you in place until you finish "moving". You could try using an avatar with its head offset set to some point behind it.
